# Jump to next field when maxlength reached

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two `<p:inputMask>` fields to save a phone number. I want to put the focus on the second field as soon as the `maxlength` of the first is reached.

Here's my code

```
<h:outputLabel value="DDD:" />

<p:inputMask mask="(99)"
             size="2"
             maxlength="2"
             value="#{cadastroFuncionarioMB.telefoneFuncionario.ddd}" />

<h:outputLabel value="Número:" />

<p:inputMask mask="9999-9999"
             size="11"
             maxlength="10"
             value="#{cadastroFuncionarioMB.telefoneFuncionario.numero}" />
```

Comment: For my case i used a inputText component and used a jQuery mask with it, it's completely help you.

Comment: You can use `onkeyup` event listener of `inputMask`, check if max length is reached, and if yes switch the focus to second field.